# Is there an AndroidManifest editor for Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Doing a tutorial I have to change the permission on the manifest. The image show like a wizard to activate permission. But in Visual Studio only have the text editor.

[image]

Do Visual Studio have an editor like that?

Comment: Your screenshot shows the editor in Visual Studio for Mac. It was former called Xamarin Studio.

Comment: @tequilaslammer Ok but visual studio 2017 doesnt have anything like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows `Visual Studio 2017` you can right click on your project and goto `Properties`

[image]

Click properties you will see:

[image]

You can select `Android Manifest` from there.

**Or**

You can just click on `Project`

[image]

and then click on your project properties:

[image]

Now you can select Android Manifest:

[image]

On scrolling down after selecting `Android Manifest` you can see the list of permissions:

[image]

Comment: can I modify the permissions?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes just modify and press `Ctrl + S` to save. Just check the box for your required permission and save it

Comment: Thanks I couldn't test it yesterday because was already out office. The permission list is on the bottom and didn't appear on the picture. Maybe you could update the 2nd picture to make it clear? I could replace with one of mine but my VS is all white

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac and found the solution today.

[Right click on AndroidManifest.xml.This provides numerous options, but select the first one "Open With", and then select "Source Code Editor"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifmjo.png)

[This will open up the editable source file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo0Ll.png)

This is particularly useful when you need to update certain permissions, such as adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`, which allows for making API calls - [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)